# InvalidIndexError while concatenating multiple dfs as list object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate multiple `df`s as per the following codes. Idea is to read excel files from local drive and then `append` the same as `pd.DataFrame` object in a list. And finally `pd.concat()` that list.

```
dfs = []
date =[]
for f in file_list:
  wb = load_workbook(os.path.join(file_path,f),data_only=True)
  sheet_name = [s for s in wb.sheetnames if 'Ageing' in s]
  ws = wb[''.join(sheet_name)]
  data = []
  for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=10,min_col=2,max_row=ws.max_row,values_only=True):
    data.append(row)
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df.columns = df.iloc[0]
  df = df.drop(index=0,axis=0).reset_index()
  df = df.dropna(axis=0,how='all').dropna(axis=1,how='all').reset_index()
  d_f = f.split('_')[2][:-5]
  date.append(d_f)
  df['Date'] = datetime.strptime(d_f,'%d%m%Y')
  dfs.append(df)
```

When I am trying `df_f = pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)` I am getting the below error:

```
 InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I have even tried the below trick:

```
 df_f = pd.concat([i.reset_index() for i in dfs],axis=0)
```

But no luck!!

Any clue on this? I have never faced this issue so far. Or what I am missing out?

Comment: Do you want to concat them horizontally or vertically? Maybe axis=1 is what you want?

Comment: Can you give a minimal example where it fails?

Comment: @IoaTzimas: No I want them to be concatenated using `axis=0`

Comment: @mozway: I am afraid reproducing the example is difficult.

Comment: Can you then provide the files?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check, if maybe you have multiple columns with the same name in your Excel sheets?

Because while this works:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1], 'y':[2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y': [4, 5], 'z':[6, 7]})
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

... this gives you an InvalidIndexError:

```
df2.columns = ('y', 'y')
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```